# Where does jsdom download resources?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom

I'm working with Node.js and jsdom to find and download all the css/js/images on a page, and then rewrite the urls to be relative (like wget --page-requisites --convert-links). But I'm wondering if I even have to do all that work if jsdom already fetches resources. If I turn on FetchExternalResources, then what does jsdom do with them? Are they stored in memory somewhere that I can save them to disk?

```
require('jsdom').defaultDocumentFeatures = {
  FetchExternalResources   : ['script', 'css', 'link', 'img'],
  ProcessExternalResources : true,
  MutationEvents           : false,
  QuerySelector            : false
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jsdom currently only fetches javascript and keeps it in memory. If you'd like to fetch other assets you will need to bake in that functionality.  You could for instance: `doc.getElementsByTagName('img')`, loop through them, fetch, and store the images to disk.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing currently. Pretty trivial with http-get. But I was hoping jsdom would have a shortcut for it already. Just in case I miss a background-image in some inline css or something like that. Thanks for the clearification!